# Are Python ints thread-safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, python-3.x

Are Python ints thread-safe? I cannot find a definitive answer for this from Google.

Comment: Do want to ask this question now for every datatype in Python?

Comment: @Sentinel: What's really interesting are the cases in which there is a level of atomicity guaranteed, but not thread safety.

Comment: @Sentinel: It is very ambiguous in the Python 3 docs

Comment: There is nothing ambigious. It's a well-known and documented fact that tuple, strings and ints are immutable. So the question about thread-safety is completely pointless here.

Comment: Quote: "But then the thread safety issue is "Is computing a value and assigning it to a shared variable thread safe?" and that answer would be "No.", for some values of "No.", and particularly "No." if the computed value involves the shared variable."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the other have said, Python objects are mostly thread-safe. Although you will need to use Locks in order to protect an object in a place that require it to go through multiple changes before being usable again.

Comment: "Mostly thread-safe" doesn't inspire confidence for building large scale software, the language implementation specs should be clear?

Comment: If you want thread safety, then use locks and read the documentation to understand what you are doing. Using locks is pretty much standard when working with multiple threads where you may access the same data from these threads.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, they are immutable, just like strings. The code `x += 1` actually creates a brand new integer object and assigns it to `x`.

In case it's not clear, things that are immutable are automatically thread safe because there is no way for two threads to try to modify the same thing at the same time. They can't be modified you see, because they're immutable.

Example from the interpreter:

```
>>> x = 2**123
>>> x
10633823966279326983230456482242756608
>>> id(x)
139652080199552
>>> a = id(x)
>>> x+=1
>>> id(x)
139652085519488
>>> id(x) == a
False
```

Comment: Still doing  `x += 1` from two threads simultaneously on the same `x` is potentially unsafe integer operation because it's not guaranteed to be atomic (just like in almost every other language). It's very probably atomic on cPython because of the GIL, but that's just a side-effect of an implementation detail.

Comment: @Rosh Oxymoron: This is true. But then the thread safety issue is "Is computing a value and assigning it to a shared variable thread safe?" and that answer would be "No.", for some values of "No.", and particularly "No." if the computed value involves the shared variable.

Comment: So, just to make things clear, simple access of a shared int's value is thread-safe, correct? There is no potential for a corrupted value when simply doing, say "print x" where x is shared. It is only in the context of larger operations or setting of the shared variable that thread-safety via locking needs to be considered.

Comment: @papercrane - ints (like strings and floats) are constant values. They cannot be modified. So there is no possibility that an individual int will change while it's being printed, or even change at all. If you're talking about the value of 'x'. Yes, it can change. But you will never see it 'in the middle' of a change. It will always be one thing or another. But the int that is being referenced by any particular variable will never change. It is absolutely and completely immutable in all ways by everything everywhere in the Python program.

Answer (score 5):

Int in Python is immutable which means it cannot be modified later, and any value change is a process of assigning a new immutable Int object to the original one.

But it never means any operation in Python syntax is thread-safe even GIL effects.
For example: x+=1 is not thread-safe at all.

To ensure thread-safety in your code, you need to find if the operation on one object is thread-safe.
The object itself does not guarantee thread-safety, nor GIL does.

Reference:
[is += in python thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359985/is-in-python-thread-safe)