# is += in python thread safe?

Tags: python

```
globalnum = 0
n = 1

class T( threading.Thread ):
  def run( self ):
    global globalnum
    globalnum += n

for _ in xrange( 0, 999 ):
  t = T()
  t.start()

print globalnum
```

the result is 999
In my test i seems += thread safe
My question is: is += really thread safe?

Comment: Do you believe that any two of your threads were actually running at the same time?

Comment: Trying to ascertain thread-safety by means of a test is a sign of ignorance or madness. The point about things _not_ being thread-safe is that you cannot rely on a particular behavior just because you have seen it a few million times with no deviation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`+=` is not threadsafe ([source](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe.htm)).

Comment: The link is dead (I can't find it on archive.org), do you have another source?

Answer (score 20):

No, it isn't thread-safe as the operation `x += 1` takes 4 opcodes as shown below:

```
  4           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 INPLACE_ADD         
              7 STORE_GLOBAL             0 (x)
```

selected out of:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def test():
...     global x
...     x += 1
...     
... 
>>> dis.disassemble(test.func_code)
  4           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 INPLACE_ADD         
              7 STORE_GLOBAL             0 (x)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```